# Change post date format to hebrew calendar

Tags: localization, post-meta, calendar

I've a wordpress site with Arabic language, it display the date of post using Gregorian calendar like this `24 فبراير 2016` in hebrew calendar it would be `24 شباط 2016` how can easily do this on any theme ??

Comment: Skimming through [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) on the definition of the *Hebrew calendar*, it looks like it's a *Lunisolar calendar* with 29 or 30 days per *Hebrew month*, so I guess this calendar change is more than just renaming month strings?

Comment: actually these names are Arabian names but in the hebrew calendar, I need to change month name "text" only. may re translate these from somewhere on wordpress core help me with this. you can see this reference [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_names_of_calendar_months#Levant_and_Mesopotamia) .. @birgire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disclaimer

This is not a complete answer, because I can't really handle signs I don't know. It should help to point you in the right direction.

### My (basic) solution

Taken from [StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17946727/1365666), I created this function for your `functions.php`:

```
function ArabicDate( $time = false ) {

    if ( $time === false ) {
        $time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
    }
    $months = array("Jan" => "يناير", "Feb" => "فبراير", "Mar" => "مارس", "Apr" => "أبريل", "May" => "مايو", "Jun" => "يونيو", "Jul" => "يوليو", "Aug" => "أغسطس", "Sep" => "سبتمبر", "Oct" => "أكتوبر", "Nov" => "نوفمبر", "Dec" => "ديسمبر");
    $your_date = date( 'y-m-d', $time ); // The Date calculated from the $time variable
    $en_month = date("M", $time );
    foreach ($months as $en => $ar) {
        if ($en == $en_month) { $ar_month = $ar; }
    }

    $find = array ("Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed" , "Thu", "Fri");
    $replace = array ("السبت", "الأحد", "الإثنين", "الثلاثاء", "الأربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة");
    $ar_day_format = date('D', $time); // The Current Day
    $ar_day = str_replace($find, $replace, $ar_day_format);

    $standard = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
    $eastern_arabic_symbols = array("٠","١","٢","٣","٤","٥","٦","٧","٨","٩");

    // use this line to format your arabic date
    $current_date = $ar_day.' '.date( 'd', $time ).' / '.$ar_month.' / '.date( 'Y', $time );
    $arabic_date = str_replace($standard , $eastern_arabic_symbols , $current_date);

    return $arabic_date;

}
```

This is not the best solution, as you have to hardcode the timeformat for your arabic date. I would love to do better, but I have no idea how to confirm if the output of the signs is correct.

Change `$ar_month` to `date( 'm', $time )` if you want the month to be numbers, not the month in text, for example.

Afterwards, you can filter your date function with this code:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'f711_convert_to_arabic_date', 10, 3 );
function f711_convert_to_arabic_date( $the_date, $d, $post ) {
    $posttime = strtotime( $post->post_date );
    return ArabicDate( $posttime );
}
```

Now your template tags ( `get_the_date()` and `the_date()` ) echo or return your Arabic Date.

If you want to use it in a template, just call `echo ArabicDate()` for the current time, or `echo ArabicDate( $timestamp )` for any Arabic Date.